# Land Method for Lognormal Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, excel

The Land Method is explain [here](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2016-03/documents/upper-conf-limits.pdf).

Anyone knows how I can look up the H*1-α*
It says "Tables of these values are given by Gilbert (1987, Tables A-10 and
A-12) and Land (1975). " Gilbert (1987) is not avaiable online. Is there any way to calculate this "H" value using excel or python?

Comment: Gilbert's table for 95% UCLs is available in Excel at http://www.quantdec.com/envstats/software/H_factors.xls.  (It has been corrected for typographical errors.)

Comment: @whuber Thanks a lot! It is great! I also found the pdf of the book which includes the tables. The book says for other numbers that are not available in the tables, we need to use cubic interpolation (four-point Lagrangian interpolation; Abramowitz and Stegun, 1964, p. 879) . In the excel file that you gave me, the H_factors for n=infinity, is a constant number for all "Sy"s. What is your advice? My dataset is >30,000

Comment: For a dataset that large you scarcely need Land's Method unless both (a) it closely conforms to a lognormal distribution and (b) has a high coefficient of variation.

Comment: @whuber So here is the df.column.describe() results: count: 2000, mean: 2100, std: 700, min: 740, 25%: 2100, 50%: 2150, 75%: 2200, max: 7400         What do you think? What method should be used for this dataset. I am trying to find one upper limit for my dataset. I cannot just simply say that I pick the max number, or the mean+3std. I am trying to follow the EPA proposed/approved methods. Thanks.

Comment: @whuber I appreciate if you share your opinion with me. Thanks,